# Can't add referenced assembly powershell core

Tags: powershell

I like powershell generally, but referencing assemblies as always crazy difficult.

Using powershell 6.2.  I need to create an object that lives in System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll.  That dll is sitting right in C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\ref.

Here is the offending object creation with junk params:
`New-Object PasswordDeriveBytes($null, $null, 'SHA1', 2)`

Here are my attempts to add a reference to the crypto dll with errors:

- `Add-Type -AssemblyName *System.Security.Cryptography.Csp*` # *can't find type*
- `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll` # *Cannot find path 'C:\pathToMyScript\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll' because it does not exist*
- `Add-Type -Path 'System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll'` # same error as above
- `Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\ref\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll'` # *Cannot find type [PasswordDeriveBytes]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded* (no error on Add-Type)

How do I simply add a reference to an assembly that is installed with powershell?  No amount of looking at other examples helps, it seems they usually are one of the above variations.

Comment: `[PasswordDeriveBytes]` -> `[System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes]`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is comment by @PetSerAl, simply fully qualifying the type.  No need to reference the assembly.